# Does the International Affective Picture System (IAPS) contain weapon stimuli?

Tags: emotion, methodology, stimulation

I'm looking to use the IAPS for my research, but I specifically need to use images of/or containing weapons. Does anyone know if IAPS has any such stimuli, and, if so, roughly how many?

Comment: There is definitely stuff like guns in there, but not sure how many.

Answer (score 3):

Use the MAPS https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26255051

You can request from Auburn Univeristy

Answer (score 2):

I happen to have access to the IAPS and had a quick look. There are about 20 pictures that include guns, most of them are held in the hand by someone, sometimes pointed at someone. Only two are photos of just the guns. Then there are about 8 pictures involving knives, and a couple of other pictures of weapons (a rocket, a tank, two jet fighters). Finally, there are a number of mundane objects that could be used as weapons (e.g., hammers).